# Combine multiple records into one, using name from only one record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I've got a query that returns a table of technicians and the number of work orders they've filled. The problem is that sometimes technicians get entered using their full name, and sometimes they get entered using their userID. I want this table to use full names, and combine records where the userID is used with records corresponding to their full name. UserID comes as either `'FirstInitial' + 'LastName'` or `'$FirstName' + '$LastInitial'`, where + is string concatenation

Example of my table:

```
 Maddoc 74 - 229
 M74 - 21
 Maddoc7 - 14
 John Smith - 215
 jsmith - 47
 johns - 19
 Anna Kellog - 251
 akellog - 67
 annak - 14
```

What I want it to look like:

```
 Maddoc 74 - 264
 John Smith - 281
 Anna Kellog - 332
```

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT "RESPONDEDBY" AS Technician, COUNT("RESPONDEDBY") AS Tickets
FROM TRACKIT_DATA2.TrackItApp_1.vTASKS_BROWSE
WHERE DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate})
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate})
AND "RESPONDEDBY" NOT IN (SELECT "RESPONDEDBY" FROM TRACKIT_DATA2.TrackItApp_1.vTASKS_BROWSE WHERE "RESPONDEDBY" = 'EmailMonitor')
GROUP BY "RESPONDEDBY"
ORDER BY COUNT("RESPONDEDBY") DESC
```

Comment: John, thanks for the advice on a lookup table. It'll be an issue to create at first but hopefully should help me avoid these issues. The reason why they are how they are is because our ticketing system has email entry and manual entry, and the two get reconciled differently with the database. Our records stretch back about 15 years so changes like that are hard to make.

Comment: Your first column is a mess... If the amount of different techs is not very high you could `SELECT DISTICT` to get them all and then manually update with a standard one per user, then normalize creating a User/Tech table.
I suggest storing the users on a different table and using the UserID coming from that table...

Comment: you could do some string manipulation to to get all possible account names for a given full name but what if you also had a Jane Smith. Who would jsmith map to?

Comment: Bob, I'm not quite sure. I think I'd have to make a lookup table manually, and hook it up to our user creation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this query will get you the results you wanted for your example

```
CREATE TABLE tracking(name VARCHAR(50), cnt INT);
INSERT INTO tracking
VALUES( 'Maddoc 74',229),
      ('M74',21),
      ('Maddoc7',14),
      ('John Smith',215),
      ('jsmith',47),
      ('johns',19),
      ('Anna Kellog',251),
      ('akellog',67),
      ('annak',14);
WITH cte AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS rn,name,SUBSTRING(name,1,1)+SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX(' ',name,1)+1,LEN(name)) AS firstl,SUBSTRING(name,1,CHARINDEX(' ',name,1)-1)+SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX(' ',name,1)+1,1) AS flast
FROM tracking
WHERE name LIKE '% %')
SELECT MIN(c.name),SUM(t.cnt)
FROM tracking t
INNER JOIN cte c
ON t.name = c.name
OR t.name = c.firstl
OR t.name = c.flast
GROUP BY rn;
```

You will have issues if you also have a Jane smith, John Sanders, etc. this also doesn't account for middle names in the full name